# Why aren't the table headers using the width setting?

Tags: html, css

The point of this pen is to have the body of the table scroll without scrolling the header.
That part works, but I can't get the headers to spread out within the Html body to match the data rows.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, in advance, for the help.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKmQgE)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

thead {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

;
thead tr td {
  min-width: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

tbody {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block
}

tbody tr {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

tbody tr td {
  min-width: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Header A</td>
        <td>Header B</td>
        <td>Header C</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[screen capture of codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfZK5.png)

Comment: If you are trying to insert a Table inside HTML or JS file. You have to ADD into it with DIV. So create a DIV on the body, then add another 3 Divs or 3 Table. But I would use DIV instead of Tables. Remember that each DIV has to reside inside the other. Like: <Div> <Div> </Div></Div>.

Comment: if you reset display values on table element, you loose the table-layout algorythm behavior. there's no more cols and rows to draw, just elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple syntax error. You have a `;` at the end on line 5.
Remove it and enjoy your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around` in your `thead tr` styles.

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  height: 100vh; 
}
div { 
  background-color: green; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
table { 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;  
}
thead { 
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
thead tr { 
  background-color: orange; 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
thead tr td { 
  min-width: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block; 
}
tbody { 
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue; 
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
}
tbody tr { 
  background-color: aqua; 
  width: 100%; 
  display: block; 
}
tbody tr td {
  min-width: 30%; 
  width: 30%; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
          <td>Header A</td>
          <td>Header B</td>
          <td>Header C</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a simple scrolling table and fixed header, with column width control using display blocked items.

See jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/xjq41yng/4/

```css
table {
  width: 100%; /* your table width */
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr,
td,
th {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

thead th {
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
}

tbody td {
  background: aqua;
}

tbody {
  height: 120px; /* fixed tbody height to show scroll example */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 30%; /* your column width */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header A</th>
      <th>Header B</th>
      <th>Header C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```